# Styling mat-tab labels -Angular Material

Tags: angular, angular-material

I'm trying to figure out how to change the color of the mat-tab labels. I've gone through every stack overflow post related to styling mat-tabs, but none of the solutions have changed the text color from white to black;
Right now it looks like this. You can't even see the non-active tabs.
[image]

How can I get the non-active links to show up as the color black?

```html
<div class="buttonRow">
  <mat-tab-group id="linkLabel" mat-stretch-tabs class="example-stretched-tabs mat-elevation-z4" >
    <div class="tabContent" >
      <mat-tab id="tab1" label="Tab1" >  Content 1 </mat-tab>
      <mat-tab id="tab2" label="Tab2"> Content 2 </mat-tab>
      <mat-tab id="tab3" label="Tab3"> Content 3 </mat-tab>
    </div>
    </mat-tab-group>

</div>
```

css I'm using that's currently working

```css
::ng-deep.mat-tab-label.mat-tab-label-active:not(.mat-tab-disabled),
::ng-deep.mat-tab-label.mat-tab-label-active.cdk-keyboard-focused:not(.mat-tab-disabled) {
  background-color: green;

  color: white;
  opacity: 1;
}
```

End result of answer by Nathan

[image: End result]

Comment: Although it's not good practice, try adding the !important flag - 'color: white !important'. This will let you see whether you're targeting the correct element or not.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use it this way:

```css
::ng-deep .mat-tab-list .mat-tab-labels .mat-tab-label-active {
  color: red;
  background-color: green;
}
```

[Stackblitz example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mat-tab-labels-style)

Comment: Just remember that ng-deep is deprecated.

Comment: @Roy
is mat-tab-labels still exist ?

Answer (score 1):

```
** Note: Apply these styles in styles.scss**


**Active tab label colour changes:**

.mat-tab-label-active 
{
    color: #00ADEE !important;
} 

**To remove the border for the tabs:**

.remove-border-bottom .mat-tab-header 
{
    border-bottom: none;
}

**To chnage the colour of the ink bar(tab border):**

.mat-tab-nav-bar:active
{
    color: #00ADEE !important;
}
** To specify the height && color for the ink bar:**  

.mat-ink-bar{
    background-color: #00ADEE !important;
    display:block;
    height: 8px !important;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

there is no need to use `ng-deep` or global style, just use the `mat-tab-label` directive as in this example : https://material.angular.io/components/tabs/overview#tab-group-custom-label

```html
<ng-template mat-tab-label>
  <mat-icon class="example-tab-icon">thumb_up</mat-icon>
  My label
</ng-template>
```

Answer (score 0):

You might need to set the active text color to white instead

```
.mat-tab-label.mat-tab-label-active {
   color: #ffffff;
}
```

Then change the default label color to black

```
.mat-tab-label {
  color: #000000;
}
```

Comment: I removed all code related to the tabs and added your code, but the default color is still white

Comment: I added image above to show output of your code only being used.